# How to use the Yii2 GroupUrlRule() class

Tags: php, yii2, yii-routing

I want to group paths under one common path. I found in the Yii2 documentation that this can be achieved with the [`GroupUrlRule()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-groupurlrule.html) class. I can not understand where to set it. I tried to sat it as a rule to the `urlManager` in `confing/web.php` but nothing happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imagine that you have some module. Your confing/web.php file might look like this:

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\web\GroupUrlRule',
                'prefix' => 'module',
                'rules' => [
                    '/' => 'controller/index',
                    'create' => 'controller/create',
                    'edit' => 'controller/edit',
                    'delete' => 'controller/delete',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Now, by URL hostname.com/module will be called 'module/controller/index'.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in `Bootstrap` file. Example:

**project/Bootstrap.php**

```
namespace app;

use yii\base\BootstrapInterface;
use yii\web\GroupUrlRule;

class Bootstrap implements BootstrapInterface
{
    public $urlRules = [
        'prefix' => 'admin',
        'rules' => [
            'login' => 'user/login',
            'logout' => 'user/logout',
            'dashboard' => 'default/dashboard',
        ],
    ];

    public function bootstrap($app)
    {
        $app->get('urlManager')->rules[] = new GroupUrlRule($this->urlRules);
    }
}
```

**project/config/web.php**

```
return [
    // ...
    'bootstrap' => [
        'log',
        'app\Bootstrap',
    ],
    // ...
]
```

**P.S.** Bootstrap files are extremely useful with modular application structure. It is much more clear to configure module's routes inside the module's folder. For that purpose just create Bootstrap file for every module in its folder. But don't forget to update `bootstrap` section of your application config file.

Comment: Shouldn't the Module class implement BootstrapInterface? [doc-2.0: adding rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#adding-rules)

Comment: @Brainfeeder it depends. If both `Module` and `Bootstrap` files are small it makes sense, otherwise I prefer store them separately.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Do I load all module bootstraps in the main config? Or is it Ok to load them in a module config?

Comment: Personally I prefer load all module bootstraps in the main config, but it’s a matter of personal taste.